# Need help finding combinations (with specific perameters)

Tags: calculus

How do I calculate this?

I need to know possible combinations.

$54 spots

Average of $45$ numbers to choose from in each spot give or take

There can be no duplicates such as, and not limited to:
$$1,1,2,3,4$$
$$1,1,2,1,1$$
$$1,2,3,4,1$$

None of any number, no matter where, or what number, or in what sequence there can be no duplicates.

Also,

They have to be in ascending order ONLY. Order does matter.

No reverses, no first number spot center, nothing whatsoever. Just ascending order.

If someone can help me calculate this, would be so helpful, and post your answer in full!

Comment: What do you mean by "no first number spot center"? And what do you mean by "average of 45 numbers to choose from in each spot give or take" - you are working with uncertain quantities? So are you only trying to find an estimate of the number of possible sequences?

Comment: "5 spots Average of 45 numbers to choose from in each spot give or take" : what are you trying to say here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to know the number of ascending sequences of length $5$, whose entries are taken from a set of $45$ possible values.

A useful trick is to realize that every set of 5 values has only one arrangement in ascending order. And every ascending sequence corresponds to only one set of 5 values.

So the number of ascending sequences is exactly the number of 5-element subsets of a 45-element set, which is given by a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) as follows:

$$\binom{45}{5} \, = \, \frac{45 \cdot 44 \cdot 43 \cdot 42 \cdot 41}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} \, = \, \boxed{1221759 \text{ combinations}\,}$$